# Show "<hello world>" as Text in ASP.NET RadioButton

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want a RadioButton to display text like "<hello world>" (note I want the "<" and ">" characters to be displayed, not to be interpreted as HTML tag characters).

Tried something like this :

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  Text="&lt;hello world&gt;" AutoPostBack="True"   />
```

but this displays no text on the browser, and renders on client side as something like :

```
<span class="radiobutton"><input id="ctl00_mainCopy_wizard_RadioButton1" type="radio" 
... />
<label for="ctl00_mainCopy_wizard_RadioButton1"><hello world></label></span>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try double escaping it.

```
&amp;lt;hello world&amp;gt;
```